# dig @server doesn't work

Tags: dns, bind

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with BIND9, working just as a caching server (forwarding to 8.8.8.8).

When I use, for example, `dig +norecurse @l.root-servers.net www.uniroma1.it`, I obtain the following output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> +norecurse @l.root-servers.net www.uniroma1.it
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Using Wireshark I discovered that the outgoing queries are correct, but there aren't any incoming answers. Why?

P.S. Using simply `dig www.uniroma1.it` I obtain the correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with how the root name servers respond(or fail, in this case) to queries than with the dig tool itself.

The following queries to a secondary DNS server in Italy will respond appropriately:

- `dig +norecurse @dns.nic.it www.uniroma1.it`

  as will a query to one of Google's DNS servers using this:
- `dig +norecurse @8.8.8.8 www.uniroma1.it`

Off the top of my head, I don't recall how the Primary DNS servers are set up in regards to individual queries. It may be a security, or DDOS avoidance measure, but I would just be guessing at this point. Hope this helps.

**Update**: See the second comment in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269138/accepted-queries-for-dns-root-server) which gives a much better explanation of interpreting a response from the top level name servers using the dig tool.